# Fast search of lists of tuples

Tags: python, performance, list, sorting, tuples

So I have many lists of tuples pulled from a database in the format:

`dataA = [('A', 'B', 'C', D, E, F), ('A', 'B', 'C', D, E, F), ...]`

Then I have a list of tuples in the format:

`dataB = [('X', 'A', 'B', 'C', Y), ('X', 'A', 'B', 'C', Y), ...]`

I need to match the tuples from dataA to dataB by matching 'A' = 'A', 'B' = 'B', 'C' = 'C' and where D > Y > E. Where the tuples match, I will use the values 'X' and 'F'.

'A', 'B', 'C', 'X' are strings up to 16 characters. D, E, F, Y are integers.

I've tried many ways to do this (string compare, nested for-loops, set intersection) but they all are very slow. What would be the best way to accomplish this? Thank you very much

Comment: You should include what you've tried so we can try to address you problem more effectively.

Comment: Are your D, E, F & Y variables also single character strings?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
StackOverflow is not a coding or tutorial service.

Comment: @PM2Ring 'A', 'B', 'C', etc. are strings let say up to 16 characters. D, E, F, Y are integers. I should have specified earlier.

Comment: I don't think a MCVE really helps here. The OP isn't having trouble implementing an algorithm—he's implemented a whole bunch of them, and they all apparently work, and he can presumably benchmark them to tell they're not fast enough, and so on. His trouble is coming up with the right algorithm to use in the first place.

Comment: On the other hand, this isn't really a Python problem. The answer is going to be "use either a hashmap or tree of interval trees" in any language, and the fact that Python has a hashmap built in and nice syntax to build one doesn't really change anything but what the code for the easy half of the problem looks like…

Answer (score 4):

The key here is picking the right data structure. The tl;dr is that a dict of interval trees of sets is the right data structure, but that probably means little to you, and definitely doesn't explain how to get there.

Before getting into it… could you push the work to a relational database? After all, the values are "pulled from a database" in the first place, and optimizing these kinds of lookups is exactly what an RDBMS is all about. With the proper indices, `SELECT f FROM mytable WHERE a=?, b=?, c=?, ? BETWEEN e and d` should run in logarithmic time. And as a bonus, you don't need to fetch all the rows of both tables, just the ones that match.

---

First, you only want tuples there the first three values match exactly. So, you want a dict, keyed on the first three members, with the matching values:

```
dictA = {}
for a, b, c, *d in dataA:
    dictA.setdefault((a, b, c), set()).add(tuple(d))
```

This already narrows down each comparison to just a linear search over the tuples with the right `A, B, C`, rather than a linear search over all tuples. That may already be enough.

---

If not, how do you cut down that linear search?

What if, instead of a set of tuples for `A, B, C`, you had a sorted list (or a binary search tree, or whatever), ordered by `D` values? Then you could find the first one where `D > Y` in logarithmic rather than linear time. But, unfortunately, you'd still have to scan the rest of the list from there to the end, because they all have `D > Y`, and you have no idea which ones also have `Y > E` until you test them all. So you've just cut the total time by 50%, not down to logarithmic.

What if you had two sorted lists, one sorted by `D` and the other by `E`? At first this seems promising, but how do you combine them?

---

What you actually need to do is break the tuples down into non-overlapping intervals, each of which contains one or more tuples. For example, if tuple A has `D=4, E=1`, and tuple B has `D=6, B=3`, you have the interval `(1, 3)` with tuples `{A}`, the interval `(3, 4)` with tuples `{A, B}`, and the interval `(4, 6)` with `{B}`.

Then you can just store those disjoint intervals in a binary search tree (or other logarithmic data structure). Since they're disjoint, you can order it by `(begin, end, value)` lexicographically, or just by `begin`, whichever is easier for the tree API you're using.

---

So now, searching is a hash lookup on `(a, b, c)` to find a tree of disjoint `(d, e)` intervals ordered by `d`, then a logarithmic search on that tree using `y`, then a check for whether `d > y > e` for that interval, and the answer is the corresponding set `{f}` of tuples within that interval.

---

There's obviously no code for the interval disjointifying built into Python, but it's not that hard to build yourself.

In fact, there are libraries on PyPI that wrap up the whole interval-tree structure. But this isn't like a dict, where using one is dead easy even if you have no idea what hashing means. Using an interval tree is easy once you've got the abstraction firmly in your head, but painful and hard to get right before then. For example, you need to think through how your open ranges (you're testing `D < Y < E`, not the usual-for-Python half-open `D < Y <= E`) should handle edges. So, it might be worth building it manually first.

---

So putting it together, you build your data structure like this:

```
dictA = {}
for a, b, c, d, e, f in dataA:
    dictA.setdefault((a, b, c), set()).add((d, e, f))
for key, values in dictA.items():
    tree = IntervalTree()
    for d, e, f in values:
        tree.add(low=d, high=e, value=f)
    dictA[key] = tree
```

And then you use it like this:

```
for x, a, b, c, y in dataB:
    tree = dictA.get((a, b, c))
    if tree:
        d, e, fs = tree.search(y)
        if f:
            for f in fs:
                yield x, f
```

This probably isn't runnable code as-is, especially since I doubt any of the interval tree libraries have exactly this API, but this is pretty much how your code will be structured.